# Why GeoFire's GeoQuery's queryAtLocation not returning keys eventhough the lat & long within the given KMs?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am creating an Android App , an Uber Clone. In this I am using Firebase to list the rides created by the user.

The Ride stored in the following format .

```
{
  "category" : "NUVO",
  "driverids" : "",
  "drop_lat" : "40.7127753",
  "drop_long" : "-74.0059728",
  "estdate" : "Wed@Feb@28th",
  "estmile" : "4.19",
  "esttime" : "01:02@PM",
  "esttotalfare" : "4.61",
  "fareest" : "1.1",
  "g" : "t9z83wv46x",
  "l" : [ 40.674426, -73.944033 ],
  "notes" : "Gv",
  "orgin_lat" : "145 Brooklyn Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11213, USA%20New York, NY, USA",
  "request_id" : "5a75579740d166e95b8b4567",
  "requested_category" : "FAM_SUV",
  "rider_id" : "5a507bf340d16660288b4567",
  "status" : 1,
  "trip_id" : 0
}
```

Now I am Using GeoFire's GeoQuery's queryAtLocation to pick all rides with in 5 KMs from his current location.

The query uses the lat & lang from the  field "l" and compare it with the current location lat & lang of the driver.

If the list's lat & lang is within 5 KMs , it will return the key , that is the parent name of the child "l".

Now I am currently in India. I use Lockito App to fix a Mock GPS location in India. After that I create a Ride within 5 KMs radius.

Now , the ride successfully listed in the drivers list. No Problem.

**My Issue**

But When I fix a mock GPS location in USA , this flow not working. I fixed the driver location on Brookyln Childeren's Museum and also created a ride on the same museum. But GeoQuery not calling onKeyEntered . It simply exists after calling GeoQueryReady function .

I check my current Lat & Lang from the app and it returns as `40.67434763453142,-73.94402358680964`. I checked this against the lat&lang on field "l" .(refer above JSON). Both pointing to same location.

But GeoQuery failed to retrieve it

**My Question** 
Why this issue happening ?. If I use India's locations. Geoquery works perfectly .

But why it failing in USA.

You may tell ,"There will be an issue in lockito". But Lockito returning correct location lat lang . I checked it in Logcat. And , if there is a issue in Lockitto then How it working in India.

Here My GeoQoery Code :

```
 try {
            showDialog();
            double nearByDistanceRadius = 5.00d;

            com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire geoFire = new com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(childtype));
            final com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), nearByDistanceRadius);
            geoQueryEventListener=new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(final String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "The key is = ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(final String key) {
                    System.out.println("ON KEYEXITED"+key);
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    System.out.println("ON KEYMOVED"+key);
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    System.out.println("ON KEYQUERYREADY");


                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    System.out.println("ON KEYERROR"+error);
                }
            };
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(geoQueryEventListener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Above , except `onGeoQueryReady` , no method called if I use USA. But it's
working in India. Can anyone tell me why that is the case?

Comment: Cross posted on: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/130

Answer (score 1):

This maybe long gone n dusted but perhaps can help others.
Since u mention its mock GPS coordinates. and u probably manually entered them.

GeoFire uses a special g: "code" (10 digit code) which is area wise / city wise

if you use the same g code in the same city / country (India in ur case) it will work fine ! 
However,if you use the same code in another country , geoQuery will fail. To make it work. u need to add one line in your code
geoFire.SetLocation() and someone in USA needs to run that code once only. geoFire will save a special key in g: "" Location. After you have the key you can remove that line from your app.
You can use that key generated by geoFire to manually enter as many locations as you want in USA and geoQuery will always work on that !!! Make sure you use the same pattern as geoFire does.
g:
 l:
  0:
  1:

Answer (score -2):

It took a while but I figured. It's that buggy geofire dependency. Downgrade from 3.0.0 to 2.3.1 solved it.

Comment: This does not exactly sound alike a solution - and probably should have been a comment.

Comment: It is often the case. I have seen multiple occasions when geofire 3.0.0 and later does not fire onqueryReady and onKeyEntered callbacks. And the older version 2.3.1 for example fires callbacks with the same code

Comment: There may be another reason to this, eg. your application code may not be fully compatible with it. I'd rather consider it quite stable, at least while not having some outdated example, where one only has raised the version number of the library (when the major version number changes, also the API may chance).